# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.VC.Interfaces

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-mvc-5

I updated my community edition of visual studio 2017 to 15.3.0

and I got this new build error

> Build Failure. Error: Could not load file or assembly
>   '**Microsoft.VisualStudio.VC.Interfaces**, Version=15.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>   ========== Clean: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========

there is no reference error and nothing new on my project except the new VS update.

I am developing an MVC 5 runs under 4.5.1 framework.

Comment: Same issue with Visual Studio 2017 Professional 15.3.0

Answer (score 13):

**Disable `Lightweight Solution Load`**

1. Tools ➜ Options ➜ Projects and Solutions ➜ General

[image]

2. Also disable `Lightweight load` in the Properties view of the Solution:

[image]

3. Restart Visual Studio

Comment: I do not see bpth of these options in my VS 2017 15.5.4 ;(

Answer (score 9):

resoolve it by deleting

".vs" Folder
"packages" Folder
"obj" Folders
and Rebuild Solution

Comment: Deleting "packages" and "obj" did the trick for me, along with the Lightweight disabling. Thanks!

Comment: Not for everybody!

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar experience, but with Enterprise.

The error persisted until I disabled Lightweight Solution Loading, but I'm including the other steps I took in case they were pre-requisites.

- I had installed the Azure Functions Support, which wanted me to restart Visual Studio, but I didn't do that until after I started getting the build error message.
- I re-ran Visual Studio installer and clicked "Modify", even though I didn't change any options, because it wanted to do *something*, saying my installation size would decrease by 15MB.  (Some cleanup from the Azure Functions installation is my guess.)
- I disabled the Lightweight Solution Load, closes and re-opened the solution, and it finally tried to build.  It failed and I got a lot of messages about running NuGet Restore and Build in parallel, but it ran.  Once I did a manual NuGet Restore, the build worked.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Worked with me by only disabling Lightweight Solution Loading.

This problem appeared for me yesterday and I ran a repair on my installation. Today I enabled Lightweight Solution Loading again and the problem returned. I hope MS fix this soon.

Anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting .vs folder worked for me

Answer (score 0):

If you need to keep Lightweight Solution Load enabled, or don't have the option to disable it, then modifying your Visual Studio install to include "Desktop development with C++" will add the missing file and repair the issue.

[image: Desktop development with C++]

Source: [Microsoft Visual Studio Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/98761/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoftvisualstu-1.html)