# Error when opening Unity shader file in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2017

Whenever I open a Unity shader file in Visual Studio, I get the error message below

[image]

In ActivityLog.xml, the error says

```
LegacySitePackage failed for package [Visual C++ Package]Source: 
'Microsoft.VisualStudio.VC' 
Description: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.VisualC.Utilities, 
Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one 
of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file 
specified.System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 
'Microsoft.VisualStudio.VisualC.Utilities, Version=15.0.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its 
dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.VisualC.Utilities, Version=15.0.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' at 
Microsoft.VisualStudio.VC.ManagedInterop.Initialize(IServiceProvider 
serviceProvider) WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned 
OFF. To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value 
[HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind 
failure logging. To turn this feature off, remove the registry value 
[HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
```

Comment: Have you tried enabling assembly bind failure logging? There is a [tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/fuslogvw-exe-assembly-binding-log-viewer) from Microsoft that makes it easier. See what that reports and update the question with the results.

Comment: Also, a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45695002/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-visualstudio-vc-interfaces). See if one of those solutions helps.

Comment: I tried that `fuslogvw` program that you suggested, but it didn't show anything.  One of the answers in the second link that you posted suggested installing "Desktop development with C++".  I did that, and it solved the problem.  Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem by going to `Tools -> Get Tools and Features` and installing "Desktop development with C++""

[image]

Comment: This worked for me, too. I had to restart Windows after the installation of the component, though.