# Unable to load solution properties

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms

I need to modify my solution properties because of another error I'm having. After clicking properties, I see this error:

> An error occurred trying to load the page.
>   Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VSDesigner, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

The solution on [Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.VC.Interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45695002/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-visualstudio-vc-interfaces) didn't help out because I'm using VS 2019 and none of the options mentioned are visible to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same error and the following worked for me:

1. Run *Visual Studio Installer* from Programs
2. Check the .NET desktop development
3. Press <kbd>Modify</kbd> to install it (it will take a while to complete)

Comment: Where is the option to check the .Net desktop development?  I just have Modify, Launch, and More.  It's not under More.

Comment: Same. how to do the 2nd step? VS studio sucks, pathetic

Comment: Click Modify to open the list of workloads, ".NET desktop development" is one of them.
Enable it, then click the Modify button below to start the installation.

Comment: Worked like a charm (VS 17.5)